# Asp.net "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Tags: asp.net

I am facing one problem in asp.net Application with sql server database.
I am getting `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`
In my code stored procedure is taking around 43 seconds and after 30 seconds
I am getting this error. For Solving this I have analyzed many sites and found these solutions:

1. I need to set `Connection Timeout=300` in connectionString in web.config file.
   This point I have done, but still I get the same error.
2. I also need to set `commandTimeout` through code.
   My problem : I am not able to modify the default `commandTimeout`
   Because I am using `DataTier_Using_SQLClient` to connect to database.
   This does not contain the `commandTimeout` property .

   Actually default command timeout is 30 seconds only.

Comment: What is this "DataTier_Using_SQLClient"?

Comment: @user2674313 can you provide the code that is used to retrieve the results?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an Adapter

```
DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection());
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Tim B James and January Mmako

Actually I was solving one issue related to one application.
`DataTier_Using_SQLClient` is one class in my application to connect with Database.
Then forget this class.

I have solved this issue by creating connection using SqlConnection.
See the code below. Using this code you can solved the `Time Expired` Error
and can call retrieve stored procedure having one parameter that need to pass:

```
using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Configuration;
```

use the below code where you want

```
string connetionString = null;

SqlConnection connection ;

SqlDataAdapter adapter ;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

SqlParameter param ;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//You can specify this connectionString in web.config or here

connetionString = "Data Source=servername;
Initial Catalog=PUBS;User ID=sa;
Password=yourpassword;
Connection Timeout=300";


connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


connection.Open();

command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.CommandText = "sp_Retrieve_ProcedureName";


param = new SqlParameter("@paramName", ParamValue);

param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

param.DbType = DbType.Int32;

command.Parameters.Add(param);

adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);


adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;


adapter.Fill(ds);
```

you can use this `ds` (DataSet) object where ever you want.